# probleme coordinates with bigger precision then double ???

Tags: asp.net, double, decimal, coordinates

I'm developing a localization website with asp.net . the Principe of it's working the site make .kml file from data base and display it on a map .

my problem is that my coordinates that are in the database have bigger precision then double(15 characters) example : 34.25912472611852,-6.588685512542725 so i used decimal type but I'm struggling with CoordinateCollection that takes only vector with double values

this is my code help. thanks

```
public kml_createur()
{


    var document = new Document();
    document.Id = "null";
    document.Name = "null";
    LineString linestring = new LineString();
    CoordinateCollection coordinates = new CoordinateCollection();

    SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-2FB04SU\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = sys_geo_domaine_etat_db; Integrated Security=True");
     String com = "select X, Y from Coordonner where idTerrain = 1";
    SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(com, sqlcon);
    //sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    //sqlcom.Parameters.Add("@IMEI", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcom);
    sda.Fill(dt);

    try
    {
        sqlcon.Open();
        sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
             decimal lon = decimal.Parse(dr["x"].ToString());
            decimal lat = decimal.Parse(dr["y"].ToString());
```

// this is the error--------------------
                Vector v = new Vector(lon,lat);
          --------------------------

### coordinates.Add(v);

}

```
        Polygon p = new Polygon();
        LinearRing lr = new LinearRing();
        OuterBoundary o = new OuterBoundary();
        p.OuterBoundary = o;
        p.OuterBoundary.LinearRing=lr;
        p.OuterBoundary.LinearRing.Coordinates = coordinates;


        Placemark placemark = new Placemark();
        placemark.Name = "terrain";
        placemark.Geometry = p;
        document.AddFeature(placemark);
        var kml = new Kml();
        kml.Feature = document;
        kml.Feature = placemark;
        KmlFile kmlFile = KmlFile.Create(kml, true);
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("D:\\marouane\\file.KML"))
        {
            kmlFile.Save(stream);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("file created");
        }


    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(exc.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlcon.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use SqlDataReader instead of a datatable, i'm thinking that your code never extract the data.

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlcom.ExecuteReader())
{
while (reader.read())
{
decimal lon = decimal.Parse(reader("x"));
            decimal lat = decimal.Parse(reader("y"));
}
}
```

After, that, I more complete description of your error message might help.